# NEDB + CONSOLE.LOG : change in output

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

I create a database (wordinfo - nedb in memory), insert some data, and then retrieve the data (sorted) for print out with console.log.  Too easy.  Curiously, the console.log printout changes with the addition of a string:

```
wordinfo.find( { $and: [{index: {$lte: 10}},{index: {$gt: 5}}] }).sort({index: 1}).exec(function(err,docs) {
  console.log(docs);
});
```

Which yields on the console:

```
11 Mar 09:51:46 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Running myscripts
Express server listening on port 3000
[ { index: 6, value: 'Artistic', _id: 'XfudVdremMDODJWk' },
  { index: 7, value: 'Assertive', _id: 'utiSSGqGDwlD1olv' },
  { index: 8, value: 'Assessing', _id: 'zzhmecUhkUvCfnNA' },
  { index: 9, value: 'Autonomous', _id: 'QPGOZRXv48c9hvhV' },
  { index: 10, value: 'Blunt', _id: 'hrEBQ7tAXuZLAzSk' } ]
```

Now I change the print out request to include a little string identifying what is printing out ("Word info: ") like so:

```
wordinfo.find( { $and: [{index: {$lte: 10}},{index: {$gt: 5}}] }).sort({index: 1}).exec(function(err,docs) {
  console.log('Word info: ' + docs);
});
```

Which yields something different on the console:

```
11 Mar 09:52:14 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Running myscripts
Express server listening on port 3000
Word info: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[obje
ct Object]
```

The 'docs' variable now prints out as the type of each record (object) instead of the content.  Why?  What is causing the change?  Not a biggie, just curious.  TIA for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you passed a string to console.log().

Console.log() accepts the docs object you used in your first example, however in your second example you concatenated your object with a string; `console.log('Concatenation happens here' + docs)`, now the function doens't format your object as you wanted.

---

To correctly log an object pass them to the function: `console.log('Word info: ', docs)`

You can also format using `%j`: `console.log('These objects were found: %j \n Yay!', docs)`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log